# How to convert standardized outputs of a neural network back to original scale?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network

In my neural network, I have inputs varying from 0 to 719, and targets varying from 0 to 1340. So, I standardize the inputs and targets by standard scaling such that the mean is 0 and variance is 1. Now, I calculate the outputs using back-propagation. All my outputs lie between -2 and 2. How do I convert these outputs to the original scale, i.e. lying in the range (0,1340)?

EDIT: I have 1 input, 5 hidden neurons and 1 output. I have used logistic sigmoid activation function. I did the standard scaling by taking mean and then dividing by standard deviation. In particular, my output lies between -1.28 and 1.64.

Comment: There are some important pieces of information missing from your question. First, what type of neurons (or activation functions) are you using? Are they linear, sigmoidal, or something else? Neuron outputs are typically in the range (0, 1) or (-1, 1) so it isn't apparent why yours are (-2, 2). Your question also appears to imply that you can not support outliers (output values that were not in the range of your training data).

Comment: @bogatron: I have edited the question to add the details.

Comment: Are you already doing some scaling of the outputs or just the inputs?

Comment: Yes, I am subtracting each item by the mean, and then dividing by standard deviation, to make the mean zero and variance one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the mean and standard deviation of the targets are `mu` and `sigma`, the *normalized* value of a target `y` should be `(y-mu)/sigma`. In that case if you get an output `y'`, you can move it back to original scale by converting `y' -> mu + y' * sigma`.

Comment: That is not an equation. '->' was used to denote 'to'.

Answer (score 0):

The output of the [logistic sigmoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_sigmoid) function is in the range (0, 1). So to scale an output `y` to the range (0, 1340), you would simply multiply `y` by 1340.

In general, if you want to scale your logistic sigmoid output to the range `(min, max`) you would use

```
y_scaled = min + (max - min) * y
```

Comment: But, I standardized the inputs by using mean and standard deviation, and my outputs are not in range (0,1). They are in range (-1.28,1.64).

Comment: Scaling of the inputs doesn't matter with regard to the scale of the outputs. Logistic sigmoid outputs are always in the range (0, 1). So if your outputs exceed that range then you are either already scaling your outputs (which you should replace with the scaling formula in my answer) or you are not using logistic sigmoids for the outputs (in which case you need to figure out what you really are using).